# How to pass static + dynamic value to :href=""

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to pass the link to href in the format of "www.google.com/1234" to the below code.`1234` is dynamic number

`<a :href="" v-if="paramConfigMap[param].returnHTML" class="btn equity buy">Buy Fundaaaas</a>`

Comment: `<a :href="path" />` ? read the vue docs

Answer (score 1):

In Vue.js you can bind the value. For example:

```
<template>
   <a :href="'https://example.com/' + link">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: {
    link: '546'
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
    <div>
      <a :href="'https://example.com/' + link" v-if="paramConfigMap[param].returnHTML" class="btn equity buy">Link</a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                link:'user'
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```